# Why some variable in a new form i'm getting warning that they are never assigned?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the top of the new form:

```
namespace test
{
    public partial class Youtube_Uploader : Form
    {
        public class ComboboxItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }

        YouTubeService service;
        string devKey = "";
        string apiKey = "";";
        string userName = "";
        string Password = "";
        string feedUrl = "";
        string FileNameToUpload = "";
        string[] stringProgressReport = new string[5];
        long totalBytes = 0;
        DateTime dt;
        Upload upload;

        public Youtube_Uploader()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            service = AuthenticateOauth(apiKey);
            var videoCatagories = service.VideoCategories.List("snippet");
            videoCatagories.RegionCode = "IL";
            var result = videoCatagories.Execute();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                item.Text = result.Items[i].Snippet.Title;
                item.Value = result.Items[i].Id;
                upload.comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            upload.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            MakeRequest();
        }
```

For example the variable upload from Upload upload
Upload is a new form and the with the variable upload i can access to controls in the Upload designer.

There is no code in the Upload form only controls that i set them to public.

My question is why i see under upload the green line say it's not assigned and will be null ?
And you can see in the constructor i'm doing for example:

```
upload.comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

I'm not getting errors. And no exceptions.
I just wonder if it's a bad thing that i'm getting this warning ? 
All i do with the upload var is to get access to the controls of the Upload form.

Comment: You never set `upload` to anything.

Comment: @TonyLee Actually, you'd get a compile error saying `Member 'Upload.comboBox1' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do and can't do with a simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    Foo f1 = new Foo("good",6);
    Foo f2;
    string temp_string;

    // You can do this
    temp_string = f1.S;
    // Bot not this
    // temp_string = f2.S; --> Use of unassigned local variable 'f2'

    // You can also do this: 
    int temp_int = Foo.I;
    // But  not
    // temp_int = f1.I; 

    // You can do
    bool b = TestFoo(f1);
    // But not
    // b = TestFoo(f2); --> Use of unassigned local variable 'f2'
}

public class Foo {
    // static class property, can be accessed with "Foo.I"
    public static int I {get; set;}

    // instance property, can be accessed with "f1.S"
    public string S { get; set; }

    public Foo(string s, int i = 0) {
        S = s;
        I = i;
    }
}

public bool TestFoo(Foo foo) {
    return foo != null;
}
```